# proc printto: log and procedure output to same file does not flush %put output to log file

Tags: logging, sas, interactive

I am trying to redirect the log and procedure output to the same destination file for use in an interactive sas session so that I can use `tail -f` on this file.

So, I do

```
proc printo print = "/home/tq84/sas.log"; run;
proc printo log   = "/home/tq84/sas.log"; run;
```

I have set the option `logparm` to `write=immediate`.

If I try to write something into the log with `%put text;`, it does not get immediately written to `/home/tq84/sas.log`.

However, when I execute a simple `proc sql; quit;`, the previously buffered log output gets flushed to `/home/tq84/sas.log`.

I am looking for an idea on how to write both the log and procedure output to the same file *and* to flush both immediatly when they're available.

Comment: What happens with PUT, no % sign?

Comment: I think this is working as designed; I don't believe `%put` causes a log write action (so this is not possible, basically, perhaps unless you use .NET or something with EG).  Will look for documentation, as I think this has come up before perhaps on SAS-L.

Comment: If I don't call `proc printto print  = ...` (only `proc printto log = ...`), the `%put` immediatly gets output to the log file.

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe I misremember, then.  (I couldn't find any evidence of this, either way.)

Comment: @Joe, the behaviour is dependent on the value of `logparm` (and possibly other options, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me.

Starting sas with

```
C:\temp>sas -logparm "write=immediate"
```

I then issue:

```
proc printto print="c:\temp\test.log";
run;
proc printto log="c:\temp\test.log";
run;
```

I open the log file in Sublime Text having it refresh when the file does.

Then submit:

```
%put HI THERE!;
```

That does not output to the log until I issue a `PROC` statement.  (Assuming a Data Step would work too.)

If I relaunch the session and reorder the `PRINTTO`

```
proc printto log="c:\temp\test.log";
run;
proc printto print="c:\temp\test.log";
run;
```

Then

```
%put HI THERE!;
```

Goes to the log ASAP.

Comment: My guess is that order matters because of a priority handling internal to SAS.  The last submitted has priority.  If the `PRINT` is last then SAS holds until it goes past something it would have (i.e. PROC SQL).  Just a guess.